# Convergence in probability for Poisson random variables with mean 1/n

Tags: probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, random-variables

Let $X_n\sim Poisson(1/n)$ for $n\geq 1$ and $Y_n=nX_n$. Show that $Y_n$ converges to $0$ in probability as $n\to \infty$.

Comment: what have you tried ? Where are you stuck ? What is the difficulty in computing $$\lim_{n\to \infty }\mathbb P(nX_n\geq \varepsilon )\ \ ?$$

Comment: I tried Chebyshev and Markov type bound but they do not go to zero.

Comment: Tchebychev ? Not here ! You know the law of $X_n$, so you can precisely compute $\mathbb P(nX_n\geq \varepsilon )$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(Y_{n}> {\epsilon})=\mathbb{P}(X_{n}> \frac {\epsilon} {n} )$

and so for $n>\epsilon$ :

$\mathbb{P}(X_{n}> \frac {\epsilon} {n} )=\mathbb{P}(X_{n}> 0 )=1-exp(-\frac 1{n} )$

which tends to zero as n approaches infinity .

note that $X_{n}$ has values in $\mathbb{N}$ and so $(X_{n}> 0 )=(X_{n}> \frac {\epsilon} {n} )$

Comment: it does my friend because Xn has values in N

Comment: i said for n> epsilon

Comment: now it works :)